# Can I ask about installation of an operating system distribution over a server?

Tags: discussion

I did purchase a set of servers, that normally doesn't allow manual installation of an operating system. It comes with a CD and it only allows a specific operating system.

Here can I ask about how to manually install an operating system on a server that initially does not permit?

Comment: I appreciate that you make the effort to ask before if a question is welcome on out site, but both of your meta questions are really vague. More details would be helpful.

Comment: It also doesn't help if you delete the question before anyone has read it!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the specifics, I guess it might have a good chance of

- being about an unsupported environment. If the vendor only supports FooOS on it's devices and you want to to run a strange port of BarOS on it, this would fit this description.
- is about some kind of policy/licensing/whatever circumvention.

both of which would make it off-topic. Please name the products in the question, so we don't need to discuss FooOS....

Comment: Just asked it, as all the components I'm working with is main stream (servers, OS) hopefully I will get an answer for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that your question would be well received, when all is said and done, purchasing hardware that has specific OS requirements and then trying to install a different OS is somewhat outside reasonable business information technology management practices.

Having said that the litmus test is to just ask and see what happens.

Comment: Actually you asked it on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/601235/ubuntu-server-installer-does-not-recognize-the-hard-drives-on-a-raid-based-serve) which is probably as good a place as any.